# export table to CSV in Redshift using R PostGreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, csv, export

I connect to Redshift using R remotely from my workstation.

```
install.packages("RPostgreSQL") 
library (RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con1 <- dbConnect(drv, host="url", port="xxxx", 
                  dbname="db_name", user="id", password="password") 

dbGetInfo(con1)
```

then I create a table:

```
dbSendQuery(con1, "create table schema.table_name as select * from schema.table_name;")
```

now I want to export this table to a .csv file on my workstation, how to do this ? Again, I don't have PostGres database installed on my workstation, only using R to get to it.

Also, this table is LARGE, 4 columns, 14 million rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pull down the results of a query into a local object, then dump the object to a CSV. Something along the lines of `res <- dbSendQuery(con1, "select * from schema.table_name"); dat <-dbFetch(res); readr::write_csv(dat, "~/output.csv")` should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after posting - sharing..

```
 system.time( fwrite(dbReadTable(con1, c("schema","table")), file="file.csv", sep=",", na="", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE ))
```

I hear feather is even faster ?

this was for 43 million rows with 4 columns, took 15 minutes.